# java/SQL code, Inserting to postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have tried to insert this data into my table in postgres, but i get this error: 
    **ERROR: syntax error at or near "left"**
The following is my insert and the following parameters...

```
public static void Add(int i, int p) throws SQLException{
    String path = p + "/";

    st = "INSERT INTO melvin_ifis_network (link_id, length, area, up_area, elevation, links_drop, longest_channel_length, to_border, left, right, parent_link, travel_time07, layer, ial, ia_connected, h_order, ia_outlet, branch_layer, memory, branch, model) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    state = connection.prepareStatement(st);
    state.setInt(1, i);
    state.setInt(2, 0);
    state.setInt(3, 0);
    state.setInt(4, 0);
    state.setInt(5, 0);
    state.setInt(6, 0);
    state.setInt(7, 0);
    state.setInt(8, 0);
    state.setInt(9, 0);
    state.setInt(10, 0);
    state.setInt(11, p);
    state.setDouble(12, 0.0);
    state.setInt(13, 0);
    state.setBoolean(14, true);
    state.setBoolean(15, true);
    state.setInt(16, 0);
    state.setBoolean(17, false);
    state.setInt(18, 0);
    state.setInt(19, 0);
    state.setInt(20, 0);
    state.setBoolean(21, true);
    state.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error cause `left, right` are reserve word. You will have to escape them using double quote `" "` like `"left"` and `"right"`

Answer (score 2):

`left` (and `right`) is a reserved word. You need to quote it: `"left"`

For more details on the rules about identifiers see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS